# Диспетчер устройств и путь к экземпляру

Tags: windows

Меняется ли этот путь когда нибудь ? или он всегда статичный ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**
Методом проб:

При вытаскивании / вставке устройства - не меняется

При отключении / включении устройства - не меняется

При удалении / восстановлении устройства - не меняется

При перезагрузке - не меняется

**Доп вопрос:**

Как присваивается этот путь ?

Что если 2 одинаковых устройства будут воткнуты по очереди в один и тот же USB ?

Им будет один и тот же адрес присваиваться или разный ?

Comment: Скорее всего да, если воткнуть видюху в другой `pci-e`. Но это надо проверить.

Comment: @donRumata интересует не именно видюха, а любое устройство. Остаётся ли адрес статичный, если устройство остаётся в том же `PCI/USB` и т.д. и просто отключается / включается - удаляется / восстанавливается. Восстанавливается - имеется ввиду обновляется конфигурация оборудования после удаления устройства (rescan) чтобы его вернуть.

Comment: Ну с усб - вообще несложно проверить прям щас. У меня винды под рукой нет, но узнать тоже было бы интересно.

Comment: `ven` и `dev` обозначают производителя и девайс, `rev` видимо ревизию устройства. Эти значения привязаны к самое железке

Comment: чтиво на тему https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-for-pci-devices

Comment: @teran вот у меня ещё такой путь к экземпляру есть: `SWD\MMDEVAPI\{0.0.1.00000000}.{B0878C22-D81A-4C19-B34B-5FCCF58D62F6}`

Answer (score 1):

Путь к экземпляру устройства - это [Device Instance ID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids), строка, которая уникально идентифицирует экземпляр устройства в системе. Ее содержание определяется драйвером контроллера шины, к которому подключено устройство. Состоит из двух частей:

- Идентификатора типа устройства. Обычно включает имя шины, код производителя и/или код модели и не зависит от порта подключения.
- Идентификатор экземпляра устройства (когда к компьютеру подключено два устройства одного типа, идентификатор экземпляра используется, чтобы их различать). В общем случае он является функцией от серийного номера устройства и/или порта подключения.

Device Instance ID гарантированно сохраняется при перезагрузках системы (т.е., когда компьютер выключен, а затем включен с тем же устройством на том же порту). Во всех иных случаях, например, при переключении устройства на другой порт или переустановке его драйвера, постоянство Device Instance ID в общем случае не гарантируется.

---

Конкретно для USB-устройств, при использовании стандартного драйвера USB-контроллера: если устройство имеет серийный номер, то ему будет присвоен тот же Instance ID при подключении к другому порту. Если у устройства нет серийного номера или он совпал с серийным номером другого уже подключенного устройства (что может случиться, когда производители не заморачиваются с уникальными номерами, а используют что-то вроде 12345678), то Instance ID будет основан на номере порта и не будет сохраняться при переключении на другой порт. Большинство запоминающих устройств, как правило, имеют серийный номер, а USB-клавиатуры и мыши обычно не имеют.

Следует помнить, что стандартные драйвера для контроллеров USB 3.0 появились только с Windows 8. Поэтому на предыдущих системах для них используются нестандартные драйвера, которые могут иметь другое поведение.